# deactivate the current sheet before going to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting error while swapping with two sheets.
I open one sheet and paste some data in this,after that I call a function which opens another sheet.but when I again paste data in the first sheet it throws error.

```
For y = 1 To size
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:Template\Mapping.xlsx")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowCntr).Value = "abc"
    newValue= getNewValue()
    rowCntr=rowCntr+1
Next

public Function getNewValue()
    Dim newV=123
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:Template\Mapping - Development v1.0.xlsx")
    getNewValue=newV
End Function
```

For the first time it works properly but after calling the function `getNewValue()` it throws error "Subscript out of range" at Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowCntr).Value = "abc" line.

Please help.

Comment: `Dim newV=123` is invalid. You cannot initialize variables in VBA.

Comment: The issue could be something to do with the fact that you've named both your open workbooks "src". Name the second one something different. That and what Paul Ogilvie above said. you have to declare your variables and then set the value.

Answer (score 2):

Your code example is incomplete. Noteably, it doesn't define what `src` is, but that is exactly what the error is: I must assume that `src`is a global variable and you set `src` in both your main function and in function `getNewValue`.

When `getNewValue` returns, `src` now points to another workbook in which your ranges don't exist.

Further I am not sure whether opening the workbook again and again results in it being reloaded, reset or that multiple copies will be opened. I suggest you open them only once, e.g.:

```
Dim src as Object
Dim src2 As Object

Function main (size As Integer)
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim rowCntr As Integer
    Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:Template\Mapping.xlsx")
    Set src2 =  Workbooks.Open("C:Template\Mapping - Development v1.0.xlsx")

    For y = 1 To size
        src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowCntr).Value = "abc"
        newValue= getNewValue()
        rowCntr=rowCntr+1
    Next
End Function

Public Function getNewValue()
    Dim newV
    newV = 123
    '...whatever you want to do...
    getNewValue = newV
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

no need for selection/activation, use objects (workbook, range) reference instead, like follows

```
Set src = Workbooks.Open("C:Template\Mapping.xlsx") '<~~ open workbook outside the loop since it doesn't depend on it
For y = 1 To size
    src.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowCntr).Value = "abc" '<~~ use "src" workbook reference to point to it whatever may be the currently active workbook 
    newValue= getNewValue()
    rowCntr=rowCntr+1
Next
```

Comment: Note that it seems that `src` is a global variable and it gets set in both the main function and in `getNewValue()`. Something will go wong there!

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie you're right. But I concentrated on the "reference vs activate" issue since the code given is too little a part of it to guess about what is going on elsewhere. It could be that, absent `Option Explicit` statement, it's using local scoped and implicitly Variant variables. And from that wrong dim statement I'd much think it's like that